# Grunt Livereload through grunt-contrib-watch not refreshing browser

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm quite new to Grunt and I'm trying to enable livereload through grunt-contrib-watch plugin, but my browser is not refreshing. This is my current Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            files: ['*.html']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

I have an index.html file in the same folder as Gruntfile.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Grunt example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Grunt example</h1>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
    <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I execute "grunt watch" and after changing the index.html file I get the following message from the console:

> > File "index.html" changed.
> >     Completed in 0.000s at ...

But my browser is not refreshing. Am I missing anything? Is there any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your script block from:

```
<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Should fix it.